# pandas dataframe nested list

Tags: python, list

in my df there is a column with a list which has dicts in it:

```
[{u'value': u'de', u'id': 247793, u'key': u'wpml_language'}, {u'value': {u'1553148938': {u'utm_campaign': u'Prospecting', u'utm_medium': u'social', u'utm_source': u'facebook+instagram', u'utm_content': u'Prospecting - Lal 10 - Video Post - Slideshow 01'}}, u'id': 247794, u'key': u'before_order_cookie_xlutm_params_utm'}, {u'value': {u'1553148938': {u'utm_campaign': u'Prospecting', u'utm_medium': u'social', u'utm_source': u'facebook+instagram', u'utm_content': u'Prospecting - Lal 10 - Video Post - Slideshow 01'}}, u'id': 247795, u'key': u'after_order_cookie_xlutm_params_utm'}, {u'value': {u'1553148938': {u'HTTP_REFERER': u'http://instagram.com/'}}, u'id': 247796, u'key': u'before_order_cookie_xlutm_params_server'}, {u'value': {u'1553148938': {u'HTTP_REFERER': u'http://instagram.com/'}}, u'id': 247797, u'key': u'after_order_cookie_xlutm_params_server'}, {u'value': u'1553148938', u'id': 247798, u'key': u'first_occurrence_timestamp_start'}, {u'value': u'1553149857', u'id': 247799, u'key': u'first_occurrence_timestamp_end'}, {u'value': [], u'id': 247800, u'key': u'_subscription_switch_data'}, {u'value': u'4937253596059', u'id': 247864, u'key': u'_shipping_phone'}, {u'value': u'B02-0078864-9488729', u'id': 247866, u'key': u'amazon_billing_agreement_id'}, {u'value': u'P02-3740043-3868412-A074831', u'id': 247868, u'key': u'amazon_authorization_id'}, {u'value': u'P02-3740043-3868412-C074831', u'id': 247869, u'key': u'amazon_capture_id'}, {u'value': u'1', u'id': 247876, u'key': u'_wcdrip_tracked'}, {u'value': u'1', u'id': 247908, u'key': u'_pys_purchase_event_fired'}, {u'value': u'Closed', u'id': 247909, u'key': u'amazon_authorization_state'}, {u'value': u'Completed', u'id': 247910, u'key': u'amazon_capture_state'}]
```

is there a way, to extract a specific key/value pair, without knowing the position or if its in there at all?
e.g., I need the following information:

> u'utm_medium': u'social'
>   u'utm_source': u'facebook+instagram'

the medium and the source can of course be different.

Thanks a lot,
E.

Comment: Wait a second... this is not pandas...

Comment: sure, I need to do it in pandas for each line ;)